# silverlight map mousemove finished event

Tags: c#, silverlight, mouseevent, mousemove

I am developing on Silverlight.
I want to raise an event when move event of the mouse is finished.

```
radMap.MouseMove += (s, e) =>
            {
                var position = e.GetPosition(s as RadMap);
                var location = Telerik.Windows.Controls.Map.Location.GetCoordinates(radMap, position);
                CurrentMouseLocation = string.Format("{0}, {1}", location.Latitude.ToString("F6"), location.Longitude.ToString("F6"));
            };
```

Above is my mouse move event.
when this event is finished, I want to raise another event.
I did not find any way to perform it.
Can anyone please help me what can be done to do so.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want to detect when the movement is over. The mouseEvents can't tell you whether the user stopped moving it any further. You have to decide upon a timespan that will be used to detect "movement stopped". On every MouseMove you have to reset a timer and when eventually the timer fires you can raise your own `MouseMovementStopped` event.

Comment: @WebAshlarEmailTest: And does it solve your problem?